# assets in assets/javascripts loading, but JS inaccessible from static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

thank you for taking a look at my question.

I am working on a simple rails 3 app, just to learn the framework, and basically I have some trouble understanding the asset pipeline.

I have a file called map.js in app/assets/javascripts, the file contains a simple google maps initialize function.

I am using require_tree (ie I have `//= require_tree .` in my application.js file), and when I visit `http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js` I do see that the map.js file has been pulled into application.js

I have the following application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
    <script>
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>   
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Even though map.js is being loaded into application.js file, calling the initialize function yields a reference error (initialize is not defined). How do I get access to the initialize function (which is loaded into application.js) from the inline script tag. If I include the javascript manually by using `javascript_include_tag` ie `<%= javascript_include_tag "map.js" %>` , the map renders and everything works properly, but I am worried about the js file being loaded twice.

I have two questions.
 Why can I not access the initialize function from an inline script tag in application.html.erb file even though it is being loaded?
 Is there a better way to remedy this situation than a manual include?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tried calling this function from web developer or sth like it?

Comment: I bet the problem is that you call this code before dom finished loading and even before js files are loaded (they are appended before closing `</body>` by defualt

Comment: where do you have `application.js` included, I don't see it in above code?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel my understanding was that you do not need to include application.js in you application.html.erb file, as this is done automatically by rails?

Comment: No, it is not. Rails is not magic, it's just a framework ;)

Comment: What's more you should have this include by default in `application.html.erb` so put it back if you deleted it

Comment: Thanks to you both, and Michael you are absolutely correct, I don't know where I got that idea, perhaps I was taking the general convenience of rails for granted :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () { 
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    }
</script>
```

add this to you application.html.erb:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

also all the js files have to be on the assets/javascripts folder

and the application.js
should have this:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Agreed - it may work, or maybe not.  It seems rails selectively includes files it finds in tree (even if you follow the silly naming conventions, which just add to the confusion).  And when you push to production, start all over with the blind-troubleshooting.   When you tire of the "assets" game, and move to putting your scripts inline, be sure to include "data-turbolinks-eval=false" in your script tag, or Rails will dutifully ignore what you typed - Its a Version 4 "feature".